Retrieving String Data from Python Callback Function in C# Console Application Using Python.Runtime
I'm working on a C# .NET Console application where I need to integrate Python functionality for audio transcription. The Python script uses a callback function to print partial transcripts from an ongoing transcription process. I'm successfully calling the Python script using Python.Runtime, but I'm struggling to capture the string data output from the Python callback function directly in my C# application. complete python script code https://docs.speechmatics.com/tutorials/using-mic
Here's the relevant part of the Python script (transcription.py):
def print_partial_transcript(msg):
    print(f"[partial] {msg['metadata']['transcript']}")

In my C# application, I'm using Python.Runtime to invoke this script and attempting to capture the output from print_partial_transcript. The Python script is added as a file in my project, and I'm able to start it without issues. However, I'm not sure how to capture the callback output in C#.
using Python.Runtime;

public void StartTranscription()
{
   Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\python311.dll";
   PythonEngine.Initialize();

    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic pyScript = Py.Import("transcription");
        // Here, I need to somehow capture the output from print_partial_transcript
    }
}


How can I capture the output from the Python callback function in my C# application in real-time?
Is there a better approach to integrate Python callback functionality within a C# application using Python.Runtime?


I suggest you the following strategy:

Get the output of your Python script and save it in the C# variable.
Invoke the specific output variable on Runtime.

OR
You can directly assign a variable and invoke it on the Runtime.
Follow the link for more information:
https://somegenericdev.medium.com/calling-python-from-c-an-introduction-to-pythonnet-c3d45f7d5232
